Performance Issue When Writing Polars.DataFrame to .parquet File
Description:
I am updating my dataset (in Parquet format) but encountering performance issues. The dataset is quite large (28 million rows), so I can’t post it here in full, but (hopefully) I will describe the problem clearly.
The issue occurs when I combine two DataFrames and write the result back to Parquet. Here’s the simplified code:
df_old.write_parquet("df_old.parquet") # costs 5.8s
df_to_append.write_parquet("df_to_append.parquet") # costs 0.4s

result = pl.concat([df_old, df_to_append])
result.write_parquet("result.parquet") # costs 1m 37.3s !

Also reading this parquet file is slow.
pl.read_parquet("df_old.parquet") # 0.5s
pl.read_parquet("df_to_append.parquet") # 0.0s
pl.read_parquet("result.parquet") # 3.6s !


I tried it in my office, slow. And now at home, slow as w(h)ell. So I guess it's machine independent.

What I Have Tried:

The row counts look correct, as expected.

df_old
# shape: (27_796_178, 13)

df_to_append
# shape: (1_144_920, 13)

result
# shape: (28_941_098, 13)


The schemas for df_old and df_to_append are identical, and they match result as well.

df_old.schema
Output: Schema([('datetime', Datetime(time_unit='ns', time_zone=None)),
        ('trading_date', Date),
        ('sec_code', String),
        ('contract_code', String),
        ('open', Float64),
        ('high', Float64),
        ('low', Float64),
        ('close', Float64),
        ('vwap', Float64),
        ('open_interest', Float64),
        ('volume', Float64),
        ('amount', Float64),
        ('offset', Int64)])

df_to_append.schema
Output: Schema([('datetime', Datetime(time_unit='ns', time_zone=None)),
        ('trading_date', Date),
        ('sec_code', String),
        ('contract_code', String),
        ('open', Float64),
        ('high', Float64),
        ('low', Float64),
        ('close', Float64),
        ('vwap', Float64),
        ('open_interest', Float64),
        ('volume', Float64),
        ('amount', Float64),
        ('offset', Int64)])

result.schema
Output:Schema([('datetime', Datetime(time_unit='ns', time_zone=None)),
        ('trading_date', Date),
        ('sec_code', String),
        ('contract_code', String),
        ('open', Float64),
        ('high', Float64),
        ('low', Float64),
        ('close', Float64),
        ('vwap', Float64),
        ('open_interest', Float64),
        ('volume', Float64),
        ('amount', Float64),
        ('offset', Int64)])


Despite these checks, I’m still facing a huge delay when writing the concatenated result to Parquet. I have no idea what to do next. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Info:
Python 3.13 with polars 1.12.0
Here’s a sample view of df_old:
df_old:polars.DataFrame

If possible, add some code to create mocked data which can be used to reproduce your problem (even if it's just generating dataframes with millions of rows of random data).
Have you tried rechunking as in pl.concat([...], rechunk=True)?

Solved! pl.concat([...], rechunk=True) turned the dataframe to a good one, which leads to another question: intuitively, same data should have same behavior, which in this case, it doesn't. Is this a intended behavior of parquet or polars?

My understanding is that it is a "bug" and Polars should detect a rechunk is needed. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/19628 being a recent example of a fix for a similar type of slowdown.
